# onClick event is not working on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this function and i call it with onClick. On Google Chrome (windows) is working but on the Android Chrome is not. How can i make it to work ontouch, in Android Chrome?

Thank you!

```js
function copyCupon(cupon, link) {
  var copyText = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(copyText);
  copyText.setAttribute("id", "copyTextId");
  copyText.setAttribute('value', cupon);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(copyText);
  alert("Cuponul " + "'" + copyText.value + "'" + " a fost copiat. Spor la cumparaturi! :)");
  window.open(link);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyCupon('test to copy', 'http://www.google.ro')">Copy coupon</button>
```

Comment: *"How can i make it to work ontouch"*. Listen ontouch event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle using jQuery.

```js
$('#btn').on('touchstart click', function() {
  var cupon = $('#btn').attr('val1');
  var link = $('#btn').attr('val2');
  var copyText = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(copyText);
  copyText.setAttribute("id", "copyTextId");
  copyText.setAttribute('value', cupon);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(copyText);
  alert("Cuponul " + "'" + copyText.value + "'" + " a fost copiat. Spor la cumparaturi! :)");
  window.open(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn' val1='test to copy' val2='http://www.google.ro'>Copy coupon</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

- Remove any hover rules or any CSS rules for the button and check if it works.
- Add cursor `pointer` to the button style
- Use jquery `touchstart`:

> $('#whatever').on('touchstart click', function(){ /* your code */ });

Answer (score 2):

Adding cursor: pointer; to the css does the trick for me, but can't offer any explanation why.

```js
function do_something() {
alert('It works now!')
}
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class='button' onclick='do_something()'>Click</button>
```

```
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```